# Android Animation Alpha

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin, alpha

I've got animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">  
   <alpha  
       android:fromAlpha="0.2"  
       android:toAlpha="1.0"  
       android:duration="500"/>  
</set>
```

and `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listViewIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/settings" 
    android:alpha="0.2"/>
```

and code:

```
final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listViewIcon);
anim .setFillAfter(true);
iv.startAnimation(anim);
```

So at the beginning I have `ImageView` with alpha `0.2` and at the end I want to have `ImageView` with alpha `1`. But it doesn't work like that - when animation starts more alpha is added and animation finish with alpha `0.2`

What do I have to change to animate my image from `0.2` up to `1`?

I've checked with different settings - I set `android:alpha="1.0"`, `fromAlpa="1.0"`, `toAlpha="0.2"` it works like I expected - from alpha `1` to `0.2`. It looks like alpha from `ImageView` is multiplied by alpha from animation...

Comment: To prevent the view from jumping back to 0.2 alpha at the end, use the `fillAfter` attribute: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:fillAfter

Comment: it's not the case. Alpha doesn't go to 1. When I animate from 1->0.2 it works fine and stays at 0.2(I use fill after). When I want to animate from 0.2 to 1 it fades to almost 0 and goes to 0.2

Comment: have you set `fillEnabled` to true?

Answer (score 120):

Try this

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);
animation1.setDuration(1000);
animation1.setStartOffset(5000);
animation1.setFillAfter(true);
iv.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: reove alpha from imageview proprties and uninsatll app from your device. clean, build and install again. because it is working my side

Comment: I don't want to remove alpha - image should be faded with alpha 0.2. Aplication is doing some stuff and when is ready I want to have my image animated to alpha 1.

Comment: Please check edited code its working fine on my google nexus 4. My imageview alpha is 0.2 at start but after applying animation it changed to 1.0 and changes persist.

Comment: I did it different way - instead of setting alpha in layout or by setAlpha/setImageAlpha I made animation 0.2->1 and put it onCreate. Now when my animation is triggered it goes perfectly from 0.2->1

Answer (score 57):

Might be a little late, but found a [lovely solution](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view) in the android docs.

```
//In transition: (alpha from 0 to 0.5)
view.setAlpha(0f);
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.animate()
   .alpha(0.5f)
   .setDuration(400)
   .setListener(null);

//Out transition: (alpha from 0.5 to 0)
view.setAlpha(0.5f)
view.animate()
   .alpha(0f)
   .setDuration(400)
   .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
           view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
    });
```

Comment: that's what i'm looking for

Comment: Works great, thanks! Just wondering though, would `.setListener(null);` potentially remove/interfere with other listeners, e.g. onClick/onTouch listeners?

Answer (score 43):

### • `Kotlin Version`

Simply use `ViewPropertyAnimator` like this:

```
iv.alpha = 0.2f
iv.animate().apply {
    interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    duration = 500
    alpha(1f)
    startDelay = 1000
    start()
}
```

Comment: This is the only working solution when trying to mix beginDelayedTransition with ImageView.animate alpha animation.

Comment: Yey! great answer! long live Kotlin!

Answer (score 18):

Setting alpha to `1` before starting the animation worked for me:

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);
animation1.setDuration(500);
iv.setAlpha(1f);
iv.startAnimation(animation1);
```

At least on my tests, there's no flickering because of setting alpha before starting the animation. It just works fine.

Comment: This worked for me too (edit: my mistake, I DO have XML interference: android:alpha="0"). Will play around with this a bit, but I do need it to start at 0 so this works for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This my extension, this is an example of change image with FadIn and FadOut :

```
fun ImageView.setImageDrawableWithAnimation(@DrawableRes() resId: Int, duration: Long = 300) {    
    if (drawable != null) {
        animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(duration)
             .withEndAction {
                 setImageResource(resId)
                 animate()
                     .alpha(1f)
                     .setDuration(duration)
             }

    } else if (drawable == null) {
        setAlpha(0f)
        setImageResource(resId)
        animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(duration)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm...

The thing is wrong, and possibly in the proper operation of the animations in the Android API.

The fact is that when you set in your code alpha value of 0.2f is based on the settings in the xml file for android it means that :

```
0.2f = 0.2f of 0.2f (20% from 100%) ie from 0.2f / 5 = 0.04f
1f = 0.2f
```

So your animation in fact works **from 0.04f to 0.2f**

flag `setFillAfter(true)` certainly works, but you need to understand that at the end of your animation `ImageView` will have the alpha value **0.2f** instead of one, because you specify 0.2f as marginally acceptable value in the animation (a kind of maximum alpha channel).

So if you want to have the desired result shall carry all your logic to your code and manipulate animations in code instead of determining in xml.

You should understand that your animations directly depends of two things:

- LayoutParams of Animated View
- Animation parameters.

Animation parameters manipulate your LayoutParams in **setFillAfter\setFillBefore** methods.

Comment: Yes. You are right. When i change start layout params at my code it was worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

The "`setStartOffset`" should be smaller, else animation starts at view alpha `0.xf` and waits for start offset before animating to `1f`. Hope the following code helps.

```
AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.1f, 1f);

animation1.setDuration(1000);
animation1.setStartOffset(50);

animation1.setFillAfter(true);

view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

view.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listViewIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/settings"/>
```

Remove `android:alpha=0.2` from XML-> ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
View.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            v.alpha = 0f
            v.invalidate()
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            v.alpha = 1f
            v.invalidate()


        }
    }
    false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun View.toggleAlpha(isShow: Boolean, delay: Long = 200, invisibleMode: Int = View.GONE) {
    if (isShow) animateAlpha(View.VISIBLE, delay) else animateAlpha(invisibleMode, delay)
}

fun View.animateAlpha(visibility: Int, delay: Long = 200) {
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }

    val alpha = when (visibility) {
        View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE -> 0f
        View.VISIBLE -> 1f
        else -> 1f
    }

    animate().apply {
        duration = delay
        alpha(alpha)
        withEndAction {
            setVisibility(visibility)
        }
    }
}
```